# How to code a MySQL connection in a class

Tags: php, mysql, class

I am trying to convert a Sign In system that is working under PHP5x & MySQL tp PHP 7 and MySQLi

I keep getting that the connection variable `$mysqli` is not recognized in some of the functions in the class.  I have read a lot of documentation, tried GLOBALS, and global without success.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
include("constants.php");

class MySQLDB{
    var $mysqli;             //The MySQL database connection
    var $num_active_users;   //Number of active users viewing site
    var $num_active_guests;  //Number of active guests viewing site

    /* Class constructor */
    public function __construct(){      
        /* Make connection to database */
        $mysqli =  new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));   
        $mysqli->select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

        /* Calculate number of users at site */
        $this->calcNumActiveUsers();

        /* Calculate number of guests at site */
        $this->calcNumActiveGuests();
    }

    public function MySQLDB(){
        self::_construct();
    }

    function calcNumActiveUsers(){
        $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_ACTIVE_USERS;
        $result =  $mysqli->query($q);
        $this->num_active_users = $result->num_rows;
    }

    function calcNumActiveGuests(){
        $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_ACTIVE_GUESTS;
        $result = $mysqli->query($q);
        $this->num_active_guests = $result->num_rows;
    }
}

/* Create database connection */
$database = new MySQLDB;

?>
```

I get the following message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in E:\$$DEVELOPMENT\HTDOCS\MySQL\ServXchange-PHP7-MySQLi\gestion\include\database-MySQLi-Work.php on line 33

Comment: You need to learn how to use `$this` in PHP classes. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Replace all your $mysqli... with $this->mysqli. You have to use $this->mysqli both when you get and set if you want the variable be reachable outside of that specific scope.

Comment: Use `$this` as described above, also I would not use `var` but `private` in this case. As for your `calcNumActiveUsers` or guests I would do `SELECT count(*) as qty FROM your_table` and then return the value of the column `qty` as opposed to `$num_rows`.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: If I put this:$result = $this->$mysqli->query($q);  I get the same messages